# Ionic v3 Alert close freezes view

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I've got a login page where I can open an alert prompt via a button click to enable auto-login feature.

When the alert comes up, also the keyboard comes up and moves the view and the alert prompt up to focus on the input field of the alert. This works as expected.

But when I close the Alert Prompt via Cancel or OK Button, the login page doesn't respond any more. I have to reload the page to be able to use it.

I figured out, that the Alert close doesnt work properly and the Page doesnt get reloaded and stay in an old state (moved up to to the keyboard).

Any Ideas how to focus back on the page or to properly close the alert?

```
showAlertPrompt() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Login',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'username',
          placeholder: 'Username'
        },
        {
          name: 'password',
          placeholder: 'Password',
          type: 'password'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {}
        },
        {
          text: 'OK',
          handler: () => {}
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

Comment: Does the console / terminal show any errors?

Comment: Nope. It works if i set "keyboard.disableScroll(true);" But I don't want that.

Comment: Hmm, without any errors to work off, I'm not sure how we'd be able to figure this out. Does it show anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: No not really. The View behind the alert doesn't update properly. When the promt is closed it moves back down as normally. Clicking the button as shown on the device is not possible. But if you touch a little bit above the button then it works. So i assume, that the view stays in the state where the keyboard was active..